# Trying to allocate more RAM to Unbound and getting a warning "To fix: start with root permissions"

Tags: kernel, permissions, ram

In my `unbound.conf` file I'm setting the following:

Ensure kernel buffer is large enough to not lose messages in traffic spikes

`so-rcvbuf: 4m`

`so-sndbuf: 4m`

When I run the command `unbound` I get the below warning

```
[1603203700] unbound[4853:0] warning: so-rcvbuf 4194304 was not granted. Got 360448. To fix: start with root permissions(linux) or sysctl bigger net.core.rmem_max(linux) or kern.ipc.maxsockbuf(bsd) values.
```

```
[1603203700] unbound[4853:0] warning: so-sndbuf 4194304 was not granted. Got 360448. To fix: start with root permissions(linux) or sysctl bigger net.core.wmem_max(linux) or kern.ipc.maxsockbuf(bsd) values.
```

I'm just starting with linux systems so I'm a very beginner level with commands and permissions.
I appreciate your help with fixing this.

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this by running the following commands, note that these will not persist across reboot. To make changes across reboot edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

```
$> sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=4194304
$> sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=4194304
```

After this restart unbound and it should solve your problems

Comment: Thanks. This works after issuing the commands and restarting Unbound. I pasted these commands to `/etc/sysctl.conf` and restarted the system. I then issued Unbound again and the same problem persists. It is as if the commands didn't run on startup.

Comment: Edit: ignore that.
I needed to add only `net.core.rmem_max` without sudo sysctl -w

works!

Comment: Depending on your version of systemd, you may have to create that file in `/etc/sysctl.d/`. See this [notice](https://archlinux.org/news/deprecation-of-etcsysctlconf/)